# I can't see my data from specific domain in google analytics(GA4)

Tags: web, next.js, google-analytics, localhost, google-analytics-4

I've created new property and I've added gtag script to my next.js project but I can't collect data from specific domain ".cab".

In network tab I checked that collect api call return 204, Also as you can see in dashboard panel I can see gathered data from localhost but not my desired hostName. Everything seems correct. Can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8sTo.png)